# Is there any way to print PDF from window service C# or (Server side printing)

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I need to print pdf from web application to server connected printer. After a long search currently i am using windows form application to print pdf from the folder on server, window form application stopped when system restarts or log off, so i am trying to create window service,`enter code here` but the same code is not working on windows service.  Is there any way to fulfil my requirement.

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(filePath);
                foreach (string file in filePaths)
                {
                    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
                    info.Verb = "print";
                    info.FileName = file;
                    info.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                    Process p = new Process();
                    p.StartInfo = info;
                    p.Start();
                    p.WaitForInputIdle();
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
                    if (false == p.CloseMainWindow())
                        p.Kill();
                    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    File.Delete(file);
                }
```

Comment: The best is to use a 3rd-party library such as Aspose. Using Process.Start to delegate printing to Adobe Reader will require a winforms app (and will be somewhat unreliable too).

Comment: Is there any sample code to print pdf from asp.net rdlc report

Comment: http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfnet/Printing+PDF+Document